# Write an expression for this question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Question:**

The length $L$ of a straight straw that will just fit in a cylindrical can with a height of $8$ cm is given by :

$$L= \sqrt{8^2+(2r)^2}$$

where $r$ is the radius of the can.

A straight straw that is $3$ times as long ($3L$) just fits in a larger can that has the same height.

Write an expression for the radius of the larger can $R$ in terms of $r$.

**Attempt:**

I did:

$$3(8+2r)=8+2r$$

$$r=4$$

This is wrong though, what have I done wrong?

Thanks a  lot.

Comment: Sorry but I can barely understand your attempt. The answer is not even $r=4$ if I solve your equation.

Comment: Telling us what you "did" without telling us *why* you did so is useless. The point is that $3L=\sqrt{64+(2R)^2}$, so $3\sqrt{64+(2r)^2}=\sqrt{64+(2R)^2}$. Now solve for $R$ in terms of $r$.

Comment: I get that but it tell me my answer of -16 is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: diagram of problem]

We need to consider the above picture.

We are given the equation $L=\sqrt{8^2+(2r)^2}$ that expresses the length of the straw.

We are given that the height of the can remains the same while the straw becomes 3 times longer. So what is the new radius we need?

We simply use the Pythagorean theorem again but now our new equation is:

$$3L=\sqrt{8^2+(2R)^2}$$

Which simply comes from: $\overbrace{(3L)^2}^\text{hypotenuse}=\overbrace{(2R)^2}^\text{opposite}+\overbrace{(8)^2}^\text{adjacent}$

Substituting the previous equation for $L$, we can express $R$ in terms of $r$.